# Reference request: a PDE related to Kahler–Ricci flow

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, kahler-ricci-flow

I was reading the survey by Imbert and Silvestre where I noticed the PDE
$$
\frac {\partial u} {\partial t} = \ln(\det (D^2u))
$$
for the study of the Kahler–Ricci flow (Eq (2.2) at page 10 in Boucksom, Eyssidieux and  Guedj's *[Introduction to the Kähler-Ricci flow](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-00819-6.pdf)*). This PDE has a similar form to one that arises in my research, and I wish to know all the results corresponding to it, e.g. existence, uniqueness, regularity, etc. However, my knowledge on Kahler–Ricci flow is very poor and I'm unable to find the origin of this PDE and the related results. Could anyone help?